# Extract data from first column of a certain row using scrapy python

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a table (5 rows and 5 cols) which looks somewhat like this:

```
<tr class='A'>
    <td>
        <a href="example.com">Hello</a>
    </td>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td>
        <a href="example.com">Dummy link</a>
    </td>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td> ... </td>
</tr>

<tr class='B'>
    <td>
        <a href="example.com">Dummy link</a>
    </td>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td>
        <a href="example.com">Dummy link</a>
    </td>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td> ... </td>
</tr>

<tr class='A'>
    <td>
        <a href="example.com">Dummy link</a>
    </td>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td>
        <a href="example.com">Dummy link</a>
    </td>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td> ... </td>
</tr>

<tr class='A'>
    <td>
        <a href="example.com">Dummy link</a>
    </td>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td>
        <a href="example.com">Dummy link</a>
    </td>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td> ... </td>
</tr>

<tr class='B'>
    <td>
        <a href="example.com">Dummy link</a>
    </td>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td>
        <a href="example.com">Dummy link</a>
    </td>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td> ... </td>
</tr>
```

What I want is:

- Select the first row with class name A
- From that row, select the 1st column, the one with the link `<a href="example.com">Hello</a>`
- Retrieve the href attribute of that link ie `example.com`

What I have now is:

`response.css('tr.A td a::attr(href)').extract_first()`

which appears to work fine, but I'm not sure if `extract_first()` is acting on both `tr.A` and `td` OR just on one of them.

So I tried all the following (played around with nth-child) but none of them gave correct result.

- `response.css('tr.A:nth-child(0) td a::attr(href)').extract_first()`
- `response.css('tr.A td:nth-child(0) a::attr(href)').extract_first()`
- `response.css('tr.A:nth-child(0) td:nth-child(0) a::attr(href)').extract()`

What would be the correct way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your case the solution is:

```
td:nth-child(1)
Selects every <td> element that is the first child of its parent

>>> response.css('tr.A td:nth-child(1) a::attr(href)').extract_first()
'example.com'
```

Explanation:

```
response.css('tr.A td a::attr(href)').extract_first()
_____________________________________________________
```

here the above expression implies Select all `td` elements inside `tr` elements with class `A`, and then select all `a` elements `href` attribute, but since you are using `extract_first()` it only selects first match.

---

Well you can always test your xpath or css in shell as follows:

```
>>> from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
>>> response = HtmlResponse(url="Test HTML String", body="""
... <tr class='A'>
...     <td>
...         <a href="example.com">Hello</a>
...     </td>
...     <td> ... </td>
...     <td>
...         <a href="example.com">Dummy link</a>
...     </td>
...     <td> ... </td>
...     <td> ... </td>
... </tr>
... 
... <tr class='B'>
...     <td>
...         <a href="example.com">Dummy link</a>
...     </td>
...     <td> ... </td>
...     <td>
...         <a href="example.com">Dummy link</a>
...     </td>
...     <td> ... </td>
...     <td> ... </td>
... </tr>
... 
... <tr class='A'>
...     <td>
...         <a href="example.com">Dummy link</a>
...     </td>
...     <td> ... </td>
...     <td>
...         <a href="example.com">Dummy link</a>
...     </td>
...     <td> ... </td>
...     <td> ... </td>
... </tr>
... 
... <tr class='A'>
...     <td>
...         <a href="example.com">Dummy link</a>
...     </td>
...     <td> ... </td>
...     <td>
...         <a href="example.com">Dummy link</a>
...     </td>
...     <td> ... </td>
...     <td> ... </td>
... </tr>
... 
... <tr class='B'>
...     <td>
...         <a href="example.com">Dummy link</a>
...     </td>
...     <td> ... </td>
...     <td>
...         <a href="example.com">Dummy link</a>
...     </td>
...     <td> ... </td>
...     <td> ... </td>
... </tr>""")

>>> response.css('tr.A td:nth-child(1) a::attr(href)').extract_first()
'example.com'
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and tip! Really helpful :)

Comment: In my case I wanted the get the href of the first a in td tr so I used 'tr td a:nth-child(1)::attr(href) and worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the class, then go over the `td`and the `a` element and get the `@href` attribute value from the first element with `extract_first`

Using `xpath`:

```
print response.xpath("//tr[contains(@class, 'A')]/td/a/@href").extract_first()
```

Using `css`:

```
print response.css("tr.A > td > a::attr(href)").extract_first()
```

This is go to the `tr` which has class `A` then to the `td` inside, and from the first `a` tag, then retrieve the `href`.

Considering the html as:

```
  <table class="container">
    <tr class='A'>
      <td><a href="first_a_example.com">Hello</a></td>
      <td> ... </td>
      <td><a href="example.com">Dummy link a</a></td>
      <td> ... </td>
      <td> ... </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='B'>
      <td><a href="example.com">Dummy link b</a></td>
      <td> ... </td>
      <td><a href="example.com">Dummy link b</a></td>
      <td> ... </td>
      <td> ... </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='A'>
      <td><a href="second_example.com">Dummy link a</a></td>
      <td> ... </td>
      <td><a href="example.com">Dummy link a</a>
      </td>
      <td> ... </td>
      <td> ... </td>
    </tr>
    ...
  </table>
```